# remove response parameter in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, anchor

my site is on `MVC3` razor and on `.Net 4` framework.

I have a `href` link in my view

```
<a href="http://localhost:17238/News?NewsID=20&NewsUrl=xxx">mylink</a>
```

this links go to News action and news action is :

```
   [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index(int NewsID, string NewsUrl)
    {

        //do some process on NewsID and NewsUrl

         mymodel mm=new mymodel();
        return View(mm);

    }
```

it works fine but return url include NewsId and NewsUrl as parameter ,i know
it is normal but how can i remove all parameter when response returned from my action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to perform an HTTP 302 or 301 redirect.

```
return Redirect(); //302
return RedirectPermanent(); //301
return RedirectToAction(); //302
return RedirectToActionPermanent(); //301
return RedirectToRoute(); //302
return RedirectToRoutePermanent(); //301
```

By performing an HTTP 301 redirect you are telling the client that this is a permanent redirection (i.e. that the resource has officially been relocated). The browser may cache this redirect.

You probably don't want to do a 301 redirect; I only mention it to give a complete answer.

Comment: @motevallizadeh - Sure, I added some options for you in my answer.

Comment: also read more on 301 and 302 from [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)